# Bluetooth audio keeps stopping

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, bluetooth

I have a Lenovo Ideapad Flex 5 which as built-in Intel bluetooth.
I have paired a keyboard, mouse, and Jabra Motion headset to this computer, and everything has been working fine for many months.

However, in the last couple weeks, the Jabra bluetooth headset disconnects randomly.  The headset plays a "disconnect" tone and audio output switches to the internal speakers. If I power cycle the Jabra headset, the bluetooth will reconnect and I can select the Jabra again as the audio device.  The keyboard and mouse stay connected and continue to work.

I updated the bluetooth driver with the Windows Update version, then tried the Intel version, then tried the version from Lenovo, then rolled back to previous version.  This issue still occurs. After approx 1-2 minutes of playing audio, or trying to take a voice call, the headset disconnects.

I assumed it was the headset so I bought a new one, and it is doing the exact same thing.

There are no entries in the Windows logs related to this issue.

The first time this happened, Bluetooth completely disappeared from the system and the keyboard/mouse also disappeared. Powering off and back on did NOT restore the bluetooth device, but then after restarting again, the bluetooth device reappeared and allowed me to pair back to my devices.  This particular event has not happened again - now it's just the Jabra headset that loses connection.

All updates are installed, and everything is configured as best I can tell correctly.  I can't find an option to prevent Windows from shutting down the bluetooth to save power - that option is not visible for the bluetooth controller or peripherals.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Bluetooth shares the 2.4GHz wireless band with Wi-Fi. If you have your Wi-Fi network set to allow 40MHz-wide channels in the 2.4GHz band, it doesn't leave enough room in the band for Bluetooth to work well. So one thing to check is to make sure that your Wi-Fi network is set to only use 20MHz-wide channels in the 2.4GHz band. Also, check your battery on the headset. Lithium-ion batteries are only good for 400±100 full charge-discharge cycles before they lose a lot of capacity. If you've had that headset for over a year and charge and discharge it every day, its Li-ion battery could be dying.

Comment: @spiff Thanks, but as stated, nothing with the setup has changed (wifi bandwidth, etc). Also, as stated I bought a brand new headset and it does the exact same thing, which points to a bluetooth problem on the PC, not the headset.

Comment: Sorry I missed the fact that you'd bought a replacement. I still think you should look at your Wi-Fi 2.4GHz channel width; even if you haven't changed *your own* network settings recently, suppose you were on channel "1+", meaning you were set to a 40MHz-wide channel that takes up all the bandwidth of channels 1 and 5. If a nearby neighbor's AP moved to channel 11, that leaves almost nothing for Bluetooth. Also, check your advanced driver settings for both your Wi-Fi and your Bluetooth devices and make sure all forms of Wi-Fi/BT coexistence, including Adaptive Frequency Hopping, are enabled.

Comment: @spiff Thanks. Question: wouldn't my bluetooth mouse and keyboard also be affected by these issues if it was interference?